# Extending maps from boundaries over the handlebodies - 3/4D case

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Given a map $f : \sharp^k S^1 \times S^2 \to \sharp^lS^1 \times S^2$, under what circumstances can we extend this to a map $F : \natural^k S^1 \times B^3 \to \natural^l S^1 \times B^3$?

Comment: What's the notation $\sharp^k$ and $\natural^l$ out of curiousity?

Comment: Sharp ($\sharp$) is connect sum and natural ($\natural$) is the boundary connect sum.